# Price for Bulk product

Tags: magento-1.9, price, magento-community

I created a bulk product "ProductBK".

This product is based on 10 items of a simple product "ProductS1".

ProductS1 has a normal price if 4.99 euro and a tier price with Number=10 and Price=4.00.

If I open the single product view of ProductBK I see what I expected: ProductBK costs 40 euros instead of 49.90 euros.

The problem is in each list of products (catalog, splash pages, search pages, feed xml, etc.); in these pages I see the price based on the normal price of ProductS1, therefore 49,90 euro.

In the product page, the correct prices is shown thanks to some javascript libraries:
- /js/varien/product.js
- skin/frontend/base/default/js/bundle.js

Do you know if there is a way to get the expected price for bundle product? (or at least, the minimum price, if there are more products involved with bulk product).

I know that the query could become slower, but I definitely need of this...

Thank you in advance